# make the ball stick to the path

Tags: unity, 2d

[image: What i'm trying to do]

Hi guys , I want the ball to stick to the path and whenever it find a corner like in the image it continue normally without flying away .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why did it fail? Are you using curves to draw a path? Do you want the ball to follow the line strictly, or using physics? (as in, the line is the ground)

Comment: I didn't try nothing, I just want to solve this problem I don't care if I use physics or something else just help me to solve this problem , thanks :)

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I can't understand what your desired result is, so I can't give you a solution. A ball following a line is completely different than a ball that is bouncing on a line, different scenarios, different solutions. I'm just trying to save the time of someone giving you a solution you are not interested in.

Comment: are know man , it's not rocket science . I just want when the player touch the screen the ball move but along the path like it should collide ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a path? I mean using a line renderer to create a visual path and later on you take the positions of this path and simply let you ball follow it.

```
LineRenderer line = Get...;
ball.LookAt(line.GetPosition(currentIndex));//just an example
```

You also could try to give the ball a huge mass and no drag and move the ball with rigid.velocity = x;
This way it should fall down quicker but I´m not sure if it works and i would not recommend doing it because it´s less accurate

Comment: but LineRenderer is for 3d , I'm in a 2d game

Comment: it should work anyway also if it´s 2D. One of the vector values must be zero then. also, line renderer is just a sprite which is rendered in 3D space as every other sprite

Comment: ok , I will try it I appreciate it